# Open browser window in client system using python

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, webserver

I have a simple python server comprised of socket programming. I am using that as a web server. I want to open a browser window on the client system. If that is possible then please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`webbrowser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) module. Here is an example using `open_new.`

```
import webbrowser
...
webbrowser.open_new('stackoverflow.com')
```

Comment: I want to open window at "client" side. Not on "server" side

Comment: That isn't possible without something running on the client side.

Comment: What could that "something" be?

Comment: If you're using python, the code in the answer would work. However, you would need some type of socket communication between the client and server in order to alert the client to open the browser window.

Comment: Meaning that client should be waiting to execute the open browser command on server's behalf when told to do so..right?

Comment: But then how the new window is opened when we click on "login via fb", etc on some third party sites?

Comment: That is done through javascript. You can create new windows in javascript using `Window.open()`. You can look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web . To see exactly how Facebook logins are implemented.